# Proof that this limit equals $e^a$

Tags: calculus, limits

Can someone please explain to me why the following identity is true?
$$\lim_{x \to \infty}\left(1 + \frac{a}{x} \right)^x = e^a$$

(I'll make a notation $L$ that is equal to the limit above.)
One 'proof' I saw went something like this:
$$L = \lim_{x \to \infty}\left(\left(1 + \frac{a}{x} \right)^\frac{x}{a}\right)^a = e^a$$

That can't be right... right? Because there really is nothing stopping me from saying
$$L = \lim_{x \to \infty}\left(\left(1 + \frac{a}{x} \right)^\frac{x}{a + 1}\right)^{a + 1} = e^{a + 1}$$
but that's obviously not true.

---

**Edit:** I posted my own answer to this question, where I explain what got me confused:
► [http://math.stackexchange.com...35491#35491](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/35486/proof-that-this-limit-equals-ea/35491#35491)

Comment: What you have is incorrect... The limit of the above is $\infty$. Perhaps you meant $\displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \left( 1 + \frac{a}{x} \right)^x$ in which case it is (one of) the definitions of $e^a$.

Comment: Sorry. It was a typo. I replaced the $x$ with $1$.

Comment: You can see a proof, *inter alia*, in my answer here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/31387/please-help-me-to-show-that-ln-x-frac1-x/31396#31396

Comment: There was a previous question that treated $a=2$, but I can't seem to find it...

Comment: I really don't understand how you conclude that the last line equals $e^{a+1}$.

Comment: @Paul: What is your definition of $e^a$?

Comment: What stops you is that the argument in the first limit is doing a change of variable $u = \frac{x}{a}$ to rewrite the inner limit as $(1 + \frac{1}{u})^u$, which approaches $e$. In the second limit, that change of variable does not lead to that limit because the exponent does not match the denominator in the fraction.

Comment: @Paul: It is highly instructive to "get your hands dirty" with proofs.  If you are comfortable with the identity $e = \displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} \left( 1 + \frac{1}{x} \right)^x$, then try to mimic the proof with $\frac{1}{x}$ replaced by $\frac{a}{x}$.  If you are not comfortable with that identity, then this is a different question altogether.

Comment: I don't think your "answer" is really an answer. It might make sense added to the *question itself* rather than as a separate answer, or as a comment. But you aren't answering the question posed, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was under the impression that $\lim_{x \to \infty}\left(1 + \frac{a}{x}\right)^{x/y} = e$, regardless of what constant $y$ is. My confusion came from the fact that *usually* $\lim_{x \to \infty} x/y = \infty$, regardless of $y$. I now know that this is a special case and it is specifically required that $y = a$ and the power be $x/a$ and nothing else.

Comment: This should probably be a comment either on the question, or on someone's answer; not really an answer.

Comment: I originally wanted to post it as an edit to my question. I figured it more of an answer since it explains the cause of my confusion and addresses my question (that is, why the last identity is not correct). :) Sorry if I should have posted this as a comment/edit.

Comment: @Arturo, @Paul: I think this is (borderline) okay. Recognizing one's own difficulty, solving the problem, and posting an answer on one's own question is explicitly allowed in the SE framework.

Comment: But if this is actually something that your *learned* from one of the answers given already, then Arturo is right, you should probably post it as a comment on the answer that showed you the "way".

Answer (score 14):

You have to recall the fundamental limit $$\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x=e.$$

Think of it as a general rule like this:

$$\lim_{\star\to\pm\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{\star}\right)^\star=e,$$ where the star can be substituded by any expression (which tends to $\pm\infty$).

So $$\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}\left(1+\frac{a}{x}\right)^x=\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}\left[\left(1+\frac{1}{\frac{x}{a}}\right)^\frac{x}{a}\right]^{\frac{a}{x}\cdot x}=e^a.$$

Comment: +1, This is a great explanation for teaching students!!  I'll remember it for next time I TA undergraduate calculus.

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps you'll find instructive the following approach.

For $a>0$,
$$
\bigg(1 + \frac{a}{x}\bigg)^x  = \exp \bigg(x\int_1^{1 + a/x} {\frac{1}{u} \,du} \bigg).
$$
Since
$$
\frac{a}{{x + a}} = \int_1^{1 + a/x} {\frac{1}{{1 + a/x}}\,du}  \le \int_1^{1 + a/x} {\frac{1}{u}\,du}  \le \int_1^{1 + a/x} {\frac{1}{1}\,du}  = \frac{a}{x},
$$
we have
$$
\frac{{xa}}{{x + a}} \le x\int_1^{1 + a/x} {\frac{1}{u}\,du}  \le a.
$$
Thus, the expression in the middle tends to $a$ as $x \to \infty$, leading to 
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to \infty } \exp \bigg(x\int_1^{1 + a/x} {\frac{1}{u} \,du} \bigg) = e^a .
$$

Comment: I have a humorous name for this: explogging.  Got an intransigent limit?  Explog!

Answer (score 3):

The proof you saw is correct. I don't understand your last equation, since it is false that $\lim_{x \to \infty} \left( 1 + \frac{a}{x} \right)^{ \frac{x}{a+1} } = e$. You need to make the substitution $y = \frac{x}{a}$ and then hopefully everything will be clear.