# What is $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}(1-c^n)^\frac{n}{2}$?

Tags: calculus, limits

What is $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}(1-c^n)^\frac{n}{2}$? Where $c \in [0, 0.5)$, and $n$ is an integer. How do I calculate it?

Thank you!!!

Comment: Use $(1+x)^n\sim1+nx$.

Comment: Does this answer your question (write $n=2m$ and $a=-c^2)$?(https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/35486/proof-that-this-limit-equals-ea)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\epsilon > 0$.  Then for large $n$ we have
$$
0 < c^n < \frac{\epsilon}{n}
\\
1 > (1-c^n) > 1-\frac{\epsilon}{n}
\\
1 > (1-c^n)^{n/2} > \left(1-\frac{\epsilon}{n}\right)^{n/2}
$$
Now $\left(1-\frac{\epsilon}{n}\right)^{n/2} \to e^{-\epsilon}$
so
$$
1 \ge \limsup_n(1-c^n)^{n/2} \ge \liminf_n(1-c^n)^{n/2}
\ge e^{-\epsilon}
$$
Next, $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} e^{-\epsilon} = 1$, so finally
$$
1 \ge \limsup_n(1-c^n)^{n/2} \ge \liminf_n(1-c^n)^{n/2} \ge 1
$$
and therefore $\lim_n(1-c^n)^{n/2}$ exists and equals $1$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. Let $|c|<1$. One may write
$$
(1-c^n)^\frac{n}{2}=e^{\frac{n}{2}\ln\left(1-c^n \right)}
$$ noticing that, as $n \to \infty$, $c^n \to 0$ and
$$
\frac{\ln\left(1-c^n \right)}{-c^n}\to 1.
$$