# Calculate $\lim_{x\longrightarrow\infty} \left(\frac{x+\ln x}{x-\ln x}\right)^{\frac{x}{\ln x}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

How can I find this limit:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \left(\frac{x+\ln x}{x-\ln x}\right)^{\frac{x}{\ln x}}$$

Comment: I've tried to do ln on the two sides and than I get a multiple of x/lnx * ln(x+ln)/ln(x-lnx) and I can't continue.. I was looking for some way to get to infinity/infinity for lhopital but I couldnt

Comment: Try to reduce to an expression involving $x/\log x$ only.

Comment: How do you get $$ \frac{\ln(x+\ln(x))}{\ln(x-\ln(x))}$$

Answer (score 7):

**Hint:** Look at the simpler problem $$\lim_{u\rightarrow\infty}\left(\frac{u+1}{u-1}\right)^u$$

and consider $u=x/ \log x$. Can you make this transformation and find this limit instead?

Comment: mmm I'm trying but I can't.. is it the same way like on this post: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12307/how-to-calculate-displaystyle-lim-x-to-infty-left-fracx2x-right?rq=1

Comment: Notice that $(\frac{u+1}{u-1})^u=(\frac{u-1+2}{u-1})^u=(1+\frac{2}{u-1})^u$.

Answer (score 0):

$\lim _{x \to \infty}\left(1+\frac{2\log x}{x(1-\log x/x)}\right)^{x/\log x}=e^{2}$

$\lim_{x \to \infty}\left(1+\frac{a}{x}\right)^{x}=\lim_{x \to \infty}\left(\left(1+\frac{a}{x}\right)^{\frac{x}{a}}\right)^a=e^a$

if $a(x) \to a \ne 0$, then

$\lim_{x \to \infty}\left(1+\frac{a(x)}{x}\right)^{x}=\lim_{x \to \infty}\left(\left(1+\frac{a(x)}{x}\right)^{\frac{x}{a(x)}}\right)^{a(x)}=e^a$

Comment: can you explain please why is it true? i know that lim(1+1/x)^x is e

Comment: Can't be right, the terms are all $\ge 1$.

Comment: $e^2$ not $e^{-2}$

Comment: yes it's e^2 but how did you see that it's the answer?

Comment: yes I corrected the sign.